# IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range. DataCache.GetAchievementCacheData () (at Assets/Scripts/Mission/Plugin/DataCache.cs:329)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, unity3d-2dtools

**When I run the game using unity I get this error continuously in the console window and the loading screen is not going further next. Help me to fix this issue.**

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
>   DataCache.GetAchievementCacheData () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/Mission/Plugin/DataCache.cs:329)

**Here is my code below**

```
    using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using UnityEngine;

//Class luu mission current
public class CurrentMission
{
    public string FB_id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Mission { get; set; }

    public CurrentMission(string id, string name, string mission)
    {
        this.FB_id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Mission = mission;
    }

    public CurrentMission()
    {
        this.FB_id = "";
        this.Name = "";
        this.Mission = "";
    }
}

public class MissionDataSave
{
    public int Mission;
    public long Score;
    public int Star;
    public int Open;//0-false. 1-true

    public MissionDataSave(int mission, long score, int star, int open)
    {
        Mission = mission;
        Score = score;
        Star = star;
        Open = open;
    }

    public MissionDataSave()
    {
        Mission = 0;
        Score = 0;
        Star = 0;
        Open = 0;
    }
}

public class AchievementCache
{
    //group nhiem vu
    public int Group;
    //Level hien tai cua group
    public int Level;
    //Gia tri hien tai
    public int Value;
    //Thong bao mission hoan thanh
    public int Notify;//0 - False, 1 - true
    //public AchievementCache()
    //{
    //    this.Group = 1;
    //    this.Level = 1;
    //    this.Value = 0;
    //}

    public AchievementCache(int group, int level, int value, int notify)
    {
        this.Group = group;
        this.Value = value;
        this.Level = level;
        this.Notify = notify;
    }
    public AchievementCache()
    {
        this.Group = 1;
        this.Value = 0;
        this.Level = 1;
        this.Notify = 0;
    }
}

public class DataCache
{
    public static string FB_ID = "FB_ID";
    public static string FB_USER = "FB_USER";
    public static string Achievement_data_key = "Achievement_data_key";
    public static string Mission_data_key = "Mission_data_key";
    public static string Current_mission_data_key = "Current_mission_data_key";

    public static AchievementCache[] dataAchievementCache;
    public static MissionDataSave[] dataMissionCache;
    public static CurrentMission[] dataCurrentMissionCache;
    //public static string XML_Current_Mission_Path = "CurrentMissionSave.xml";
    //public static string XML_Data_Mission_Path = "DataMissionSave.xml";
    //public static string XML_Data_Achievement_Path = "AchievementCache.xml";

    //serialize xml theo tung phan tu

    //public static List<MissionDataSave> DeserializeMissionDataSaveListFromXML(string filePath)
    //{
    //    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    //    {
    //        Debug.LogError("File " + filePath + " not exist!");
    //        return new List<MissionDataSave>();
    //    }
    //    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MissionDataSave>), new XmlRootAttribute("MissionDataSaveRoot"));
    //    TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(filePath);
    //    List<MissionDataSave> movies = (List<MissionDataSave>)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
    //    textReader.Close();
    //    return movies;
    //}

    //public static void readXMLTest()
    //{
    //    string xmlDataCache1 = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + XML_Current_Mission_Path;
    //    TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(xmlDataCache1);
    //    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    //    xmlDoc.Load(textReader);
    //    XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
    //    Debug.Log("TRUOC");
    //    foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNodeList)
    //    {
    //        Debug.Log("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa " + node.Attributes["Id"].Value);
    //    }
    //    Debug.Log("SAU");
    //    XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    //    XmlElement elem = xmlDoc.CreateElement("CurrentMissionCache");
    //    elem.SetAttribute("Id", "112312");
    //    elem.SetAttribute("Name", "NameDG");
    //    elem.SetAttribute("Mission", "MissionDG");
    //    root.AppendChild(elem);
    //    textReader.Close();
    //    xmlDoc.Save(xmlDataCache1);
    //}

    //Add mission xml node
    public static void UpdateMissionScore(long score, int star, int mission, int open)
    {
        MissionDataSave data = dataMissionCache[mission - 1];
        if (data.Star < star)
        {
            data.Star = star;
        }
        if (data.Score < score)
        {
            data.Score = score;
        }
        data.Open = open;
    }

    public static void SaveMissionDataCache(bool submitToServer = false)
    {
        string dataSave = "";
        string dataSendServer = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < dataMissionCache.Length; i++)
        {
            dataSave += dataMissionCache[i].Mission + "-" + dataMissionCache[i].Score + "-" + dataMissionCache[i].Star + "-" + dataMissionCache[i].Open + ",";
            //Chi gui nhung mission da open len server
            if (dataMissionCache[i].Open == 1)
            {
                if (dataSendServer.Length > 0)
                    dataSendServer += ",";
                dataSendServer += dataMissionCache[i].Mission + "-" + dataMissionCache[i].Score + "-" + dataMissionCache[i].Star + "-" + dataMissionCache[i].Open;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("Data save " + dataSave);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(Mission_data_key, dataSave);
        if (submitToServer)
        {
            Debug.Log("Data send server  " + dataSendServer);
            AudioControl.getMonoBehaviour().StartCoroutine(DHS.PostMeInfoMissionUpdate(FB.UserId, dataSendServer));
        }
    }

    public static void GetMissionDataCache()
    {
        int max_mission = 100;
        if (dataMissionCache != null)
        {
            dataMissionCache = null;
        }
        dataMissionCache = new MissionDataSave[max_mission];
        //Tao moi neu chua co
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(Mission_data_key))
        {
            string datas = "1-0-0-1,";
            for (int i = 2; i <= max_mission; i++)
            {
                //Mission - Score - Star - Open
                if (DataMissionControlNew.test)
                {
                    datas += i + "-0-0-1,";

                    //if (i < 16)
                    //    datas += i + "-0-0-1,";
                    //else datas += i + "-0-0-0,";
                }
                else
                {
                    datas += i + "-0-0-0,";
                }
            }

            PlayerPrefs.SetString(Mission_data_key, datas);
        }
        string missionData = PlayerPrefs.GetString(Mission_data_key);
        string[] data = missionData.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < max_mission; i++)
        {
            string[] infoData = data[i].Split('-');
            //Debug.Log("Info " + data[i]);
            string mission = infoData[0];
            string score = infoData[1];
            string star = infoData[2];
            string open = infoData[3];
            dataMissionCache[i] = new MissionDataSave(Convert.ToUInt16(mission), Convert.ToUInt32(score), Convert.ToUInt16(star), Convert.ToUInt16(open));
        }

    }

    //-------------------------CURRENT MISSION---------------------------
    //Add current mission xml node
    public static void SaveCurrentMission(string data = "")
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            string dataSave = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < dataCurrentMissionCache.Length; i++)
            {
                if (dataSave.Length > 0)
                    dataSave += ",";
                dataSave += dataCurrentMissionCache[i].FB_id + "-" + dataCurrentMissionCache[i].Name + "-" + dataCurrentMissionCache[i].Mission;
            }
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(Current_mission_data_key, dataSave);
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(Current_mission_data_key, data);
            GetCurrentMission();
        }
    }
    public static void GetCurrentMission()
    {
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(Current_mission_data_key))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(Current_mission_data_key, "Me-User-1");
        }
        if (dataCurrentMissionCache != null)
        {
            dataCurrentMissionCache = null;
        }
        string current_data = PlayerPrefs.GetString(Current_mission_data_key);
        string[] data = current_data.Split(',');
        dataCurrentMissionCache = new CurrentMission[data.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] info = data[i].Split('-');
            //fb - User name -  missison
            dataCurrentMissionCache[i] = new CurrentMission(info[0], info[1], info[2]);
        }
    }
    public static void SetMeCurrentMission(int mission)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DataCache.dataCurrentMissionCache.Length; i++)
        {
            if ("Me".Equals(DataCache.dataCurrentMissionCache[i].FB_id))
            {
                int old = Convert.ToInt16(DataCache.dataCurrentMissionCache[i].Mission);
                if (old < mission)
                {
                    DataCache.dataCurrentMissionCache[i].Mission = "" + mission;
                    DataCache.UpdateMissionScore(0, 0, mission, 1);//Them mission moi vao xml
                }
            }
        }
        DataCache.SaveCurrentMission();
    }
    //-------------------------ACHIEVEMENT---------------------------
    //Ghi de len du lieu cu
    public static void ReplaceAchievementCache(int groupLevel, int value, int level = -1)
    {
        dataAchievementCache[groupLevel - 1].Value = value;
        if (level != -1)
        {
            dataAchievementCache[groupLevel - 1].Level = level;
        }
    }
    //Cap nhat them du lieu
    public static void AddAchievementCache(int groupLevel, int addValue, int addLevel = 0)
    {
        dataAchievementCache[groupLevel - 1].Level += addLevel;
        dataAchievementCache[groupLevel - 1].Value += addValue;

    }
    public static void GetAchievementCacheData()
    {
        Debug.Log("-------------GetAchievementCacheData--------------------");
        if (dataAchievementCache != null)
        {
            dataAchievementCache = null;
        }
        dataAchievementCache = new AchievementCache[22];
        //Tao achievement
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(Achievement_data_key))
        {
            string achi = "";
            for (int i = 1; i <= 22; i++)
            {
                achi += i + "-1-0-0,";
            }
            //Debug.Log("Create new achievement " + achi);
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(Achievement_data_key, achi);
        }
        string achievement = PlayerPrefs.GetString(Achievement_data_key);
        //Debug.Log(achievement);
        string[] achie = achievement.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i< dataAchievementCache.Length; i++)
        {
            //Debug.Log(achie[i]);
            string[] infoAchie = achie[i].Split('-'); 
            string group = infoAchie[0];
            string level = infoAchie[1];
            string value = infoAchie[2];
            string notify = infoAchie[3];
            //Debug.Log(group +" " +  dataAchievementCache[i].Group);
            dataAchievementCache[i] = new AchievementCache();
            dataAchievementCache[i].Group = Convert.ToInt16(group);
            dataAchievementCache[i].Level = Convert.ToInt16(level);
            dataAchievementCache[i].Value = Convert.ToInt32(value);
            dataAchievementCache[i].Notify = Convert.ToInt16(notify);
        }
    }
    public static void SaveAchievementCache(bool sendServer = false)
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.Log("-------------------SaveAchievementCache-----------------");
            if (dataAchievementCache != null)
            {
                string achievement = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < dataAchievementCache.Length; i++)
                {
                    string s = "" + dataAchievementCache[i].Group + "-" + dataAchievementCache[i].Level + "-" + dataAchievementCache[i].Value + "-" + dataAchievementCache[i].Notify + ",";
                    achievement += s;
                }
                //Debug.Log("----------LUU ACHIEVEMENT------------ " + achievement);
                PlayerPrefs.SetString(Achievement_data_key, achievement);
                if (FB.IsLoggedIn && sendServer)
                {
                    //Nếu chưa có playerprefs thì sẽ submit lên luôn
                    //Nếu có rồi thì phải check nó cập nhật hoàn thành từ server về thì mới cho up lên
                    bool check = !PlayerPrefs.HasKey(DataMissionControlNew.key_update_achievement_data_from_server) ||
                        (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(DataMissionControlNew.key_update_achievement_data_from_server) && PlayerPrefs.GetInt(DataMissionControlNew.key_update_achievement_data_from_server) == 1);
                    if (check)
                    {
                        AudioControl.getMonoBehaviour().StartCoroutine(DHS.PostMeInfoUpdate(DFB.UserId, "" + VariableSystem.diamond, "" + achievement, "", (www) =>
                        {
                            Debug.Log("----------Update achievement to server success!------------- " + achievement);
                        }));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Log("----------KHONG CHO UP ACHIEVEMENT VA DIAMOND LEN SERVER------------- " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt(DataMissionControlNew.key_update_mission_data_from_server, 0));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("------------ERROR ---------------" + e.Message);
            if (DataMissionControlNew.test)
            {
                MobilePlugin.getInstance().ShowToast("ERROR " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void DeleteUserData()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(FB_ID);
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(Mission_data_key);
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(Current_mission_data_key);
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(Achievement_data_key);
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("diamond");
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(DataMissionControlNew.key_update_mission_data_from_server);
        VariableSystem.diamond = 8;
        VariableSystem.heart = 5;
    }
    public static void RestoreUserData(int diamond, string achievement)
    {
        Debug.Log("Restore user data");
        VariableSystem.diamond = diamond;
        VariableSystem.heart = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("heart", 5);
        string[] achie = achievement.Split(',');
        if (achie.Length > 5)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataAchievementCache.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] infoAchie = achie[i].Split('-');
                string group = infoAchie[0];
                string level = infoAchie[1];
                string value = infoAchie[2];
                string notify = infoAchie[3];
                dataAchievementCache[i].Group = Convert.ToInt16(group);
                dataAchievementCache[i].Level = Convert.ToInt16(level);
                dataAchievementCache[i].Value = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                dataAchievementCache[i].Notify = Convert.ToInt16(notify);
            }
            //Debug.Log("---Luu achievement----");
            SaveAchievementCache();
            GetAchievementCacheData();
        }
        Debug.Log("----------------ACHIEVEMENT da dc cap nhat tu -----------------");
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(DataMissionControlNew.key_update_achievement_data_from_server, 1);

    }
```

**The line 329 is this**

```
string level = infoAchie[1];
```

Comment: if you put the `Debug.Log(achie[i]);` that you commented whats the last thing it prints before the error? and if you could print that string `string achievement` what's the content

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from the last comma you are adding in the string you are adding to your PlayerPrefs in this part:

```
if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(Achievement_data_key))
{
    string achi = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= 22; i++)
    {
        achi += i + "-1-0-0,";
    }

    //Debug.Log("Create new achievement " + achi);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString(Achievement_data_key, achi);
}
```

This code generates this string:

> 1-1-0-0,2-1-0-0,3-1-0-0,4-1-0-0,5-1-0-0,6-1-0-0,7-1-0-0,8-1-0-0,9-1-0-0,10-1-0-0,11-1-0-0,12-1-0-0,13-1-0-0,14-1-0-0,15-1-0-0,16-1-0-0,17-1-0-0,18-1-0-0,19-1-0-0,20-1-0-0,21-1-0-0,22-1-0-0,

Keep in memory that last comma at the end of the string.

You are later doing a split on the ',' character, and iterating over them.

```
string[] achie = achievement.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i< dataAchievementCache.Length; i++)
{
    //Debug.Log(achie[i]);
    string[] infoAchie = achie[i].Split('-'); 
    string group = infoAchie[0];
    string level = infoAchie[1];
    ...
}
```

The problem is that by doing so, your achie string array contains an empty last element. So when you are later splitting on the "-" character, your infoAchie string array only contains one element: the empty string. The first line:

```
string group = infoAchie[0];
```

Still works, but is filled with the empty string. Then:

```
string level = infoAchie[1];
```

Can't work, as you are indeed out of the bounds of the infoAchie array.

The solution would be to add the comma to your string only if it is not the last element.

Also, I strongly advise you to use a [StringBuilder](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-stringbuilder) over a simple string for optimization purposes. Your code could then look like, for instance:

```
if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(Achievement_data_key))
{
    StringBuilder achi = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 22; i++)
    {
        achi.Append(i).Append("-1-0-0");

        if(i != 22)
            achi.Append(",");
    }

    //Debug.Log("Create new achievement " + achi);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString(Achievement_data_key, achi.ToString());
}
```

Which generates this string:

> 1-1-0-0,2-1-0-0,3-1-0-0,4-1-0-0,5-1-0-0,6-1-0-0,7-1-0-0,8-1-0-0,9-1-0-0,10-1-0-0,11-1-0-0,12-1-0-0,13-1-0-0,14-1-0-0,15-1-0-0,16-1-0-0,17-1-0-0,18-1-0-0,19-1-0-0,20-1-0-0,21-1-0-0,22-1-0-0